# Keep prefixes in loading and writing TTL file with RDF4J

Tags: java, turtle-rdf, rdf4j

I need to load a Turtle TTL file, add some triples, then save it again.
The original TTL file has a big header containing the prefixes for some namespaces.

```
@prefix biro: <http://purl.org/spar/biro/> .
@prefix c4o: <http://purl.org/spar/c4o/> .
@prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix deo: <http://purl.org/spar/deo/> .
@prefix doco: <http://purl.org/spar/doco/> .
...
```

After I load the file and add the triples, the saved TTL won't contain the prefixes, unless I specify them manually, one by one. Is there a way to keep the namespaces already present in the loaded file?

This is my Java code:

```
// Load input TTL file
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(ttlFile);
RDFParser rdfParser = Rio.createParser(RDFFormat.TURTLE);
Model model = new LinkedHashModel();
rdfParser.setRDFHandler(new StatementCollector(model));
rdfParser.parse(stream);
stream.close();

// Code to add triples here
model.add(...);

// Save the new TTL file
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(ttlOutputFile);
RDFWriter writer = Rio.createWriter(RDFFormat.TURTLE, out);
writer.startRDF();

// Here I can add the prefixes manually
// writer.handleNamespace("dcterms", DCTERMS.NAMESPACE);

for (Statement st : model) {
    writer.handleStatement(st);
}
writer.endRDF();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code for writing to file explicitly only writes the statements themselves, not the namespaces stored in your `model` object.

You could fix it by adding something like this:

```java
model.getNamespaces().forEach(ns -> writer.handleNamespace(ns.getPrefix(), ns.getName()));
```

However, more generally, your code to write to file is more complex than it needs to be. A far simpler approach to writing your `model` object to file would be something like this:

```java
// Save the new TTL file
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(ttlOutputFile);

Rio.write(model, out, RDFFormat.TURTLE);
```

or if you prefer to use a `RDFWriter` object (so you can tweak the config):

```java
RDFWriter writer = Rio.createWriter(out, RDFFormat.TURTLE);

//... tweak writer config

Rio.write(model, writer);
```

Both of these are shorter, easier code, and they take care of namespace handling for you as well.

Similarly, reading the file can also be done more conveniently:

```java
// Load input TTL file
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(ttlFile);
Model model = Rio.parse(stream, RDFFormat.TURTLE);
```